# Twitch stream status is showing online. while user is offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, twitch

I have written a bot in NODE JS which will continuously monitor the twitch users and when some user will get online, then it will send message to "group me" app that user is online.
It is working fine. My problem is that sometimes it send message that user is online but actually user is offline.
Any idea on how to solve this?

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwZEu.jpg)

```js
var users = ["Statelinejay", "Ad_914", "Houssam06" ];
var messages = ["notsent", "notsent", "notsent" ];
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));


function theCall(index) {
    console.log('Processing ' + users[index]);

    client.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + users[index] + '?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function (data, response) {
        if (data["stream"] === null) {
            messages[index] = 'notsent';
            console.log(users[index] + 'is offline');
        } else 
            //// Start of sending message
            var myJSONObject = {
                "bot_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "text": " https://www.twitch.tv/" + users[index]
            };
            if (messages[index] === 'notsent') {
                request.post({
                        url: " https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post",
                        method: "POST",
                        json: true, // <--Very important!!!
                        body: myJSONObject
                    },

                    function (error, response, body) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
                messages[index] = 'sent';
                console.log('message sent');
            }
            //// End of sending message
            console.log(users[index] + '  is online') ;
        }
        theCall((++index % users.length));
    });
 
 
  
 
}

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
  theCall(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that data["stream"] is always null whenever the streamer is offline? Can it be undefined? Can you please try

```
if (!data["stream"])
```

instead of

```
if (data["stream"] === null)
```

?

If this doesn't work, can you console.log your data and response variables for the false online streamer, and update the question?

Comment: Yes it will be null when user is offline. data variable consists different